# How to use custom type in JPA column?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class:

```
public class Email {
  private String name;
  private String domain;
  public String toString() {
    return name + "@" + domain;
  }  
}
```

I want to use it in JPA column:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id private Integer id;
  private Email email;
}
```

This is what Hibernate says:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.XXX.Email
```

How to make it understand my custom type. I think that it's something very simple, but can't find in documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, there are a number of ways:

- annotate the `Email` class with `@Embeddable`, and have:

  ```
   @Embedded
   private Email email;
  ```
- declare a custom value type - see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2794) (using `@Type`)

Comment: @Bozho I wonder whether the second approach proposed is possible with just JPA (without Hibernate-specific annotations)?

Comment: @Vincenzo no. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628344/jpa2-0-support-of-custom-user-types-and-second-level-cache

Comment: @Bozho Can't I implement the same behavior through setters/getters?

Comment: it would be uglier than using the embeddable option. :) But you can

Comment: I have been successfully using the hibernate custom type with hibernate and spring. Now we are using JPA for new entities and hoping that hibernate can still support old hbm files that have custom type defined. However I get the same exception. All of our old hibernate mappings are externalized but new JPA entities are using annotations. Any help is appreciated. thx

Comment: @Pangea you can ask another question, providing relevant details.

Comment: hi asked another question here, appreciate the help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391287/jpa-2-and-hibernate-together-hibernate-custom-types-spring

Comment: @Bozho the link in your answer appears not to be working. I found this to be a great little article that other's may find useful:
https://jessitron.com/2020/07/24/spring-and-jpa-use-custom-value-types-inside-entities-with-a-custom-converter/

Answer (score 0):

You can make email an entity and it will work...but it's pretty ineficcient.

```
@Entity
public class Email {
  ...
}
```

Or you can swtich from `Email` to `String` and it will work. (What's the point of wrapping a String anyway?)

You can read [this tutorial](http://i-proving.com/space/Technologies/Hibernate/User+Types+in+Hibernate) about custom user types in Hibernate (since you tagged it).

Or you can use `@Embebbed` as Bozho says.