# jpa 2 and hibernate together + hibernate custom types + spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have been successfully using the hibernate custom type with hibernate and spring. Now we are using JPA for new entities and hoping that hibernate can still support old hbm files that have custom type defined. However I get the same exception. All of our old hibernate mappings are externalized but new JPA entities are using annotations. Any help is appreciated. thx

**Error**: Could not determine type for: com.equifax.aspire.persistence.framework.hibernate.EmptySupportedString

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"  value="classpath:/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="root.platform.persistence.dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>     
        <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />        
      </bean>
    </property>
   <!--<property name="loadTimeWeaver">
      <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property> -->
  </bean>
```

My custom type mapping in hbm file

```
<property name="securityCode" column="SecurityCode" type="com.persistence.framework.hibernate.EmptySupportedString"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the .hbm.xml file to the persistence.xml file. Like so:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="name">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <mapping-file>com/equifax/aspire/persistence/framework/hibernate/EmptySupportedString.hbm.xml</mapping-file>
```

That should make it available