# Can JPA be persuaded to convert between eg UUIDs and Strings?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have a Java object with a field which is a UUID. I'd like to be able to persist this object to the database in the obvious way; however, the Basic mapping will use Java serialization to write it, while I want the UUID to be present in its obvious string form.  Is there a way to supply a UUID <-> String converter to JPA for that field which will be used at read and write time so I can handle this type naturally?

Comment: @See: there are several question about this topic:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628344/jpa2-0-support-of-custom-user-types-and-second-level-cache and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828675/how-to-use-custom-type-in-jpa-column

Comment: Note: Starting from JPA 2.1, a `@Convert` annotation can be used with an `AttributeConverter<UUID, String>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chris Lercher commented [*Note: Starting from JPA 2.1, a `@Convert annotation can be used with an AttributeConverter<UUID, String>`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446378/can-jpa-2-0-be-persuaded-to-convert-between-eg-uuids-and-strings#comment-64442619).

This approach works well and is compatible with any JPA provider, whereas the `@Type(type = "uuid-char")` is provider specific.
Also, with `autoApply=true` is applied to every field of every entity, so there is no need to annotate each field in each entity. See the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Converter.html) and check the example below:

The converter class

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class UuidConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final UUID entityValue) {
        return ofNullable(entityValue)
                .map(entityUuid -> entityUuid.toString())
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public UUID convertToEntityAttribute(final String databaseValue) {
        return ofNullable(databaseValue)
                .map(databaseUuid -> UUID.fromString(databaseUuid))
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

The entity

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false, columnDefinition="CHAR(36)")
    private UUID customerId = randomUUID();

    //.....
}
```

And this is how it looks in the database

```
TABLE customer
ID  BIGINT(19)  NO  PRI (NEXT VALUE FOR SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_5D3)
NAME    VARCHAR(255)    YES     NULL
CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(36) NO  UNI NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

JPA 2.0 doesn't provide a general way to do it, except for creating separate getters/setters for different representations of the same field.

Depending on your JPA provider you can use implementation-specific methods, for example, Hibernate provides a `uuid-char` type for this purpose:

```
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
private UUID uuid;
```

Comment: I have to confess, a colleague told me that JPA 2.0 didn't provide a general way to support it and I couldn't quite believe him. Very sad. Is this need felt more rarely than I'd guess?

Comment: If you feel it's important, you can always describe your needs with rationale and send it to the JPA Users mailing list: jpa-spec.java.net/lists I do believe that you can do a lot of things using pre-* and post-* lifecycle events but perhaps it could be helpful for others.

Comment: @Paul: Actually it's a pretty common need and perhaps one of the most expected features for [JPA 2.1](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338).

Answer (score 4):

You could annotate your `UUID` property `@Transient` and at the same time provide its persistable String-based representation.

During `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate` or `@PostLoad` you'll set this String-based representation basing on `UUID` or (in case of loading it from the DB) re-create your `UUID` from the String.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of the JPA itself. There is a way using Hibernate if it is your ORM provider.

#### Hibernate 5.x

Use the `@Type` annotation with `"uuid-char"` to map into the `VARCHAR` column.

```java
@Type(type="uuid-char")
private UUID uuid;
```

Documentation: [JBoss Hibernate 5.6 User Guide | 2.3. Basic types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic)

#### Hibernate 6.x

As of Hibernate 6.x, you can use the following configuration to map them automatically:

```
hibernate.type.preferred_uuid_jdbc_type=CHAR
```

Documentation: [JBoss Hibernate 6.2 User Guide | 2.2.38. UUID](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-uuid)