# How can I store UUID (not Primary Key) as a string in Database in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, uuid

I have a problem to store UUID as a string not blob in database in Spring Boot.

UUID is stored as blob in database but I want to store it as a string.

I also use UUID as not a primary key.

How can I do that?

Here is the UUID definition in my Entity shown below.

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private UUID userUUID;
```

Comment: You have the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446378/can-jpa-be-persuaded-to-convert-between-eg-uuids-and-strings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75519977/3764965